# Adding an element to a given position in a singly linked list (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

If anyone can help me sort this issue out, I will quite literally give you my first born child. Apologies for any formatting issues etc. as this is my first time posting (please go easy on me!!).

I am currently struggling with an add method for a generic linked list class. Here is its description:
**Inserts the specified object at the specified position in this list. Shifts the object currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent objects to the right (i.e., it adds one to their indices).**

Here is the code I currently have for the method, excluding exception handling.

```
next = head;
size++;
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
     next = next.getNext();
} // for                                                                                                                                                                                    
GenListNode<T> prev = next;
GenListNode<T> current = next;
for (int count = 0; count < size - 1; count++) {
     prev = next;
     current = next;
     for (int i = count; i < size - 3; i++) {
          prev = prev.getNext();
     } // for                                                                                                                                                                                
     for (int j = count; j < size - 2; j++) {
         if (current.getNext() == null) {
             current.setNext(new GenListNode<T>());
         } // if                                                                                                                                                                             
         current = current.getNext();
      } // for                                                                                                                                                                                
current.setData(prev.getData());
} // for
next.setData(obj);
```

Here is the code my GenListNode class.

```
private GenListNode<T> next;
private T data; 

    public GenListNode(T data, GenListNode<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
        this.data = data;
    } // GenListNode                                                                                                                                                                                

    public GenListNode(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    } // GenListNode                                                                                                                                                                                

    public GenListNode() {
    } // GenListNode                                                                                                                                                                                

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    } // setData                                                                                                                                                                                    

    public void setNext(GenListNode<T> n) {
         this.next = n;
    } // setNext                                                                                                                                                                                    

    public T getData() {
         return data;
    } // getData                                                                                                                                                                                    

    public GenListNode<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    } // getNext
```

The problem I am having at the moment is that when I add an object to an index somewhere in the middle of the list it works, however when I try to add to the beginning of the list, the very last element of the list disappears. In general, this code has become somewhat convoluted and messy, and it does not do what it is supposed to do. Any help is appreciated, and if there is anything I can clarify, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure what your method is doing there, but generally to insert something to a linked list you just loop over next() until you get to the correct spot, then create a new node, set new->next = previous->next and then previous->next = new.

Comment: @azurefrog And when you say previous you're referring to the node in the spot just before the correct spot, correct?